# <code> inside <p> with automatic element clearing

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a portfolio site and I plan to annotate work with accompanying code, similar to how it is done here:
http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/

I would like to use code exactly like this, as it works well with the CMS I made.

```
<p>
    Blah blah blah
    <code>
        Annotations
    </code>
</p>
<p>
    Another para
</p>
<p>
    Blah blah blah
    <code>
        Annotations
    </code>
</p>
```

Here is a picture I have drawn. Note the preferable markup that I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I've been unable to replicate something like shown by adding clear:both to my floated paragraph element(s). Can somebody help me create this layout so that it can be achieved using the markup I'm aiming for?

Comment: Personally I would restructure the markup, maybe using (in HTML5) `article`s to contain the paragraphs, and `aside`s with `pre` elements to mark up the annotations. Your current markup seems rather fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you want to adhere to your posted layout, but there are several problems I foresee.

First and foremost, you are creating a very strange structure by having the text `Blah blah blah` and the `code` block as siblings. I don't think your layout is even possible with this syntax.

The second problem is that the paragraph tag, `p`, cannot contain block level elements. So you are severely limiting yourself to what content can be inside them when writing your pages.

I would change your structure to be something like this and then use floats to position.

```
div.parent { overflow: auto; } /* self clearing parent div */
p.left { float: left; width: 30%; } 
code.right { float: right; width: 70%; }
```

```
<div class="parent">
     <p class="left">
        Text
     </p>
     <code class="right">Code</code>
</div>
```

This allows you to position encapsulated blocks of html with float left/right. It also allows you to make use of block level elements in your description areas. In addition, I would probably go in and add classes and encapsulate the code tags in a parent div also. But I think the example is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Better yet: throw away the clearfix. Use other elements already in the layout for clearance, or apply `overflow: hidden` or `auto` to the container `div`.

Comment: Found this nice article based on BoltClock's feedback - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Thanks for that @mrtsherman and BoltClock. Just to make sure; If I don't plan to put in any images or other block elements on the left column, could I use a left floating styled <p> instead of a styled <div> for the left part?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine @kvanberendonck. I updated my answer to reflect this.